# SQL Server - How to add column with group subtotals to the query results

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2017, subtotal

I have a database table with items that are placed in a tree hierarchy. Items have their IDs and ParentIDs. Each item has an Amount assigned to it, so when I pull data on my hierarchy and its Amounts, it looks like so:

```
| ID | Name            | ParentID | Level | Amount |
| 1  | ITEM 1          |     NULL |     0 |    100 |
| 3  |  - Item 1-1     |        1 |     1 |    100 |
| 7  |  - - Item 1-1-1 |        3 |     2 |    100 |
| 8  |  - - Item 1-1-2 |        3 |     2 |    100 |
| 4  |  - Item 1-2     |        1 |     1 |    100 |
| 9  |  - - Item 1-2-1 |        4 |     2 |    100 |
| 10 |  - - Item 1-2-2 |        4 |     2 |    100 |
| 2  | ITEM 2          |     NULL |     0 |    200 |
| 5  |  - Item 2-1     |        2 |     1 |    200 |
| 11 |  - - Item 2-1-1 |        5 |     2 |    200 |
| 12 |  - - Item 2-1-2 |        5 |     2 |    200 |
| 6  |  - Item 2-2     |        2 |     1 |    200 |
| 13 |  - - Item 2-2-1 |        6 |     2 |    200 |
| 14 |  - - Item 2-2-2 |        6 |     2 |    200 |
```

Suppose this is a new table. I need select the data from it and also calculate group subtotals by Amount for each hierarchy level, like so:

```
| ID | Name            | ParentID | Level | Amount | Group rollup |
| 1  | ITEM 1          |     NULL |     0 |    100 |          700 |
| 3  |  - Item 1-1     |        1 |     1 |    100 |          300 |
| 7  |  - - Item 1-1-1 |        3 |     2 |    100 |          100 |
| 8  |  - - Item 1-1-2 |        3 |     2 |    100 |          100 |
| 4  |  - Item 1-2     |        1 |     1 |    100 |          300 |
| 9  |  - - Item 1-2-1 |        4 |     2 |    100 |          100 |
| 10 |  - - Item 1-2-2 |        4 |     2 |    100 |          100 |
| 2  | ITEM 2          |     NULL |     0 |    200 |         1400 |
| 5  |  - Item 2-1     |        2 |     1 |    200 |          600 |
| 11 |  - - Item 2-1-1 |        5 |     2 |    200 |          200 |
| 12 |  - - Item 2-1-2 |        5 |     2 |    200 |          200 |
| 6  |  - Item 2-2     |        2 |     1 |    200 |          600 |
| 13 |  - - Item 2-2-1 |        6 |     2 |    200 |          200 |
| 14 |  - - Item 2-2-2 |        6 |     2 |    200 |          200 |
```

Please, help me achieve this goal.

Right now, I am using this query to select the data. However, it doesn't order items correctly and doesn't do the rollup. Can you adjust it to both order them as shown above and calculate the group rollup?

```
WITH cte AS
  (SELECT ID,
          Name,
          ParentID,
          0 AS LEVEL,
          Amount
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE ParentID IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.ID,
          t.Name,
          t.ParentID,
          LEVEL+1,
          t.Amount
   FROM cte
   JOIN MyTable t ON cte.ID = t.ParentID)
SELECT d1.*
FROM cte d1
```

It would be nice to have a TOTAL rollup for entire table (all hierarchies) in a separate row.

Comment: What type of server are you working with? (Oracle / SQL Server / etc.) And what version? (SQL Server 2008 / SQL Server 2014 / etc.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 0):

You existing results data makes me think that you may already be using some form of recursive CTE to build up things like `Level` and `Name`. If so, this can probably be adapted to compute `hier` at the same time.

But if not, we use a recursive CTE to build up our `hier` columns and then use [`IsDescendantOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/isdescendantof-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) when computing the sums:

```
declare @t table(ID int, Name  varchar(30), ParentID int, Level int, Amount int)
insert into @t(ID ,Name , ParentID , Level , Amount) values
(1  ,'ITEM 1         ',NULL, 0 ,100 ),
(3  ,' - Item 1-1    ',   1, 1 ,100 ),
(7  ,' - - Item 1-1-1',   3, 2 ,100 ),
(8  ,' - - Item 1-1-2',   3, 2 ,100 ),
(4  ,' - Item 1-2    ',   1, 1 ,100 ),
(9  ,' - - Item 1-2-1',   4, 2 ,100 ),
(10 ,' - - Item 1-2-2',   4, 2 ,100 ),
(2  ,'ITEM 2         ',NULL, 0 ,200 ),
(5  ,' - Item 2-1    ',   2, 1 ,200 ),
(11 ,' - - Item 2-1-1',   5, 2 ,200 ),
(12 ,' - - Item 2-1-2',   5, 2 ,200 ),
(6  ,' - Item 2-2    ',   2, 1 ,200 ),
(13 ,' - - Item 2-2-1',   6, 2 ,200 ),
(14 ,' - - Item 2-2-2',   6, 2 ,200 )

;With hierarchy as (
    select ID, Name, '/' + CONVERT(varchar(max),ID) + '/' as hier,Amount
    from @t
    where ParentID is null
    union all
    select t.ID,t.Name, hier + CONVERT(varchar(max),t.ID) + '/',t.Amount
    from
        hierarchy h
            inner join
        @t t
            on
                t.ParentID = h.ID
), Typed as (
    select ID,Name,Amount,CONVERT(hierarchyid,hier) as hier
    from hierarchy
)
select
    *
from
    Typed t1
        cross apply
    (select SUM(Amount) as GroupTotal from Typed t2
     where t2.hier.IsDescendantOf(t1.hier) = 1) u
order by hier
```

Results:

```
ID          Name                           Amount      hier          GroupTotal
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ------------- -----------
1           ITEM 1                         100         0x58          700
3            - Item 1-1                    100         0x5BC0        300
7            - - Item 1-1-1                100         0x5BE7        100
8            - - Item 1-1-2                100         0x5BE880      100
4            - Item 1-2                    100         0x5C20        300
9            - - Item 1-2-1                100         0x5C34C0      100
10           - - Item 1-2-2                100         0x5C3540      100
2           ITEM 2                         200         0x68          1400
5            - Item 2-1                    200         0x6C60        600
11           - - Item 2-1-1                200         0x6C75C0      200
12           - - Item 2-1-2                200         0x6C7640      200
6            - Item 2-2                    200         0x6CA0        600
13           - - Item 2-2-1                200         0x6CB6C0      200
14           - - Item 2-2-2                200         0x6CB740      200
```

You may also, at this stage, decide that your data model needs changing so that the hierarchy is *directly* modelled using the `hierarchyid` type, rather than Parent/Child. That depends on what other uses cases this data has to satisfy.

---

The problem here is that most hierarchical queries tend to end up exploring the hierarchy top-down but the data you want is only easily obtained bottom-up. I did try to work out whether there was a clever `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` expression (the latter for use in a window function) that could also use `IsDescendantOf` but failed.

Comment: Yes, I am using a cte for selecting the hierarchy already, without ordering work it looks like so:
WITH cte AS
  (SELECT ID,
          Name,
          ParentID,
          0 AS LEVEL,
          Amount
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE ParentID IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.ID,
          t.Name,
          t.ParentID,
          LEVEL+1,
          t.Amount
   FROM cte
   JOIN MyTable t ON cte.ID = t.ParentID)
SELECT d1.*
FROM cte d1
Can you adjust it to booth order the items by their hierarchy and calculate the group rollup?

Comment: @B.Sverediuk - so take my definition for the `hier` column in my `hierarchy` CTE and add it to the set of columns in your `cte`. Add the second CTE to cast it to the correct type (`Typed` above) and then do the `cross apply` in the final select. As I alluded to when I added a comment, the problem is that you want bottom-up data but are exploring the hierarchy top-down - there's no easy way to get the sums *whilst* doing that first hierarchy construction.